# Wordpress IIS permalinks result in error 404

Tags: wordpress, iis, permalinks

I have a wordpress site in IIS and when i change the permalinks settings in wordpress to /%postname%/ i get an error 404 in every article.
The web.config file has the following

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules><rule name="Plesk. Wordpress redirect wpConfigRule #70e3895f-b537-474a-8e6e-f5c31e888d54" stopProcessing="true"><match url="^wp-config.php$" ignoreCase="false"/><action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden"/></rule>
        <rule name="WordPress: http://domain.com" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
        </rule></rules>
</rewrite>
```

which after a google search i found that is correct.
What else should i check in order to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the web.config file from the wordpress documentation?
https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite

The one you posted looks like something specific for plesk, try with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes i have and nothing